# How to get query result in table format using php-postgresql?

Tags: php, xml, postgresql

I am stuck  with displaying result into table format. I tried with all options like "pg_fetch_row, pg_fetch_array, pg_fetch_all_columns", but I am not getting results in table format.

The query part is working fine, also I am getting results in XML format, but I need to display it in table format, also it should contain a column heading.

Please can anyone suggest me how to get the results in table format.

My PHP_PostgreSQL code shown in below:

```
<?
$conn = pg_connect("user=postgres password=nkr@123 host=localhost dbname=test");
    if (!$conn) {
    echo "An error occured.\n";
    exit;
    }

$cat=$_POST['cat'];
$subcat=$_POST['subcat'];
echo "Value of \$cat = $cat <br>Value of \$subcat = $subcat \n";

$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM $cat JOIN $subcat ON $cat.districtco=$subcat.districtcode");
if (!$result) {
echo "An error occured in result.\n";
exit;
}
echo $result;
if (!$result) {
echo "An error occured in xml_result.\n";
exit;
}
?>
```

I am using this code to get results in XML:

```
$xml_result="<resultxml>";
$num = pg_num_fields($result);
while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)){
$xml_result.="<record>"; 
for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++)
{   
  $xml_result .= "<".pg_field_name($result, $i).">".$row[$i]."</".pg_field_name($result, $i).">";      
} 
$xml_result.="</record>";
}
$xml_result.="</resultxml>";
echo $xml_result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You do know you should process the result set with a for() loop, don't you?

Although psql will spit the result set from a query optionally in HTML, this only happens because psql was specifically written to do this.

Comment: Aside from your own code above, in which you can replace your XML specific tags for the HTML table tags, you can have a look at [this page](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-row.php), where you'll find plenty of information.

Comment: I already made a search in that, and also explored some examples in that, they are working fine but I am not getting results for my data. In my case, the results contains geometry columns to display.